# K-means clustering in R with the plot

Tags: r, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am writing to ask for the code below

```
set.seed(4)
x=matrix(rnorm(50*2),ncol=2)
km.out<-kmeans(x,3,nstart=20)
km.out
plot(x, col=(km.out$cluster +1),main='K-Means Clustering Results with K=3', pch=20, cex=2)
```

My question is why do we need to put `km.out$cluster +1`, why '''+1''', also the plot is colorful, is it set by default?

On linear regression or generalized linear regression, by using `plot`, using the result only shows the pic without color.

Comment: Who is telling you that you need to use +1?  Examples in ?kmeans don't have that.

Comment: Hello Elin, this code is copied from the book, An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Application in R, page 405

Answer (score 1):

This is purely about the choice of the colors. If you start at 1 with the colors, you will have a duplicate of black in your chart:

```
barplot(1:10, col=1:10)
```

[image]

While starting at 2 with a color vector won't have a duplicate:

```
barplot(1:10, col=(1:10)+1)
```

[image]

In the long term, I would advice to switch to `ggplot` as it is much more transparent about the choice of colors.

Comment: Thanks @C0bra. Can I kindly the advantages of ggplot? Also, does the explanation given by you explain the reason why we define ```col=(km.out$cluster +1)```

Comment: BTW, when using the ```plot()``` function in R, it turns out that R can automatically identify the categorical variables and there is no need to used ```boxplot()``` maybe??

Comment: @MathildaFang 
I think this post describes the reasons pretty well: https://mandymejia.com/2013/11/13/10-reasons-to-switch-to-ggplot-7/
I edited the code in the post. Note the difference in color choice of the code with and without +1.

Comment: I make perfect sense. Brilliant explanation, thanks@c0bra